# What is the error in this INSERT SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Where is the error in this query?

```
INSERT INTO chat (`id`,`user`,`message`,`date`) 
VALUES (null,'user','test',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

This is the error message I receive:

> *"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id','user','message','date') VALUES (null,'user','test',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)' at line 1"*

Comment: This is what it gives me... If I run this query from phpmyadmin it has no errors but if I use PHP mysqli (the connection is ok because I use it before this query and it works) it gives me this error...

Comment: i think date is a reserved word. are you able to rename the column into something like 'date_'

Comment: if your date type is date just use CURDATE() or Current_Date() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the id is autoincrement then use this instead

```
    INSERT INTO `chat` (`user`,`message`,`date`) 
     VALUES ('user','test',NOW());
```

Its difference between single quote `'` and backtick  `

Comment: Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id','user','message','date') VALUES (null,'user','ciao',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)' at line 1

Comment: this error is for your code not for mine , i didnt use any id :) . or its another query you are getting the error .

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user','message','date') VALUES ('user','ciao',NOW())' at line 1

Comment: I was using ' instead of ` for the fields of the query :(